# Sqlite syntax error, please tell me where it is?

Tags: sqlite

Can you guys please point me to the error? And, by the way, is there any SQLite syntax highlighter? Thanks.

```
    sqlite> .schema recordtypes
    CREATE TABLE recordtypes (record_id text primary key);
    sqlite> .schema headers
    CREATE TABLE headers (header_id text primary key);
    sqlite>                                
    sqlite> 
    sqlite> CREATE TABLE record_to_headers (id INTEGER, recordid TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(recordid) REFERENCES recordtypes(record_id), headerid TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(headerid) REFERENCES headers(header_id));
    Error: near "headerid": syntax error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to define all your field *then* map them to foreign keys, as so:

```
CREATE TABLE record_to_headers (id INTEGER, recordid TEXT, headerid TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(recordid) REFERENCES recordtypes(record_id), FOREIGN KEY(headerid) REFERENCES headers(header_id));
```

Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 4):

Put your constraints after column definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE record_to_headers (
    id INTEGER,
    recordid TEXT,
    headerid TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(recordid) REFERENCES recordtypes(record_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(headerid) REFERENCES headers(header_id)
);
```